# UISwitch in debugDescription is not showing value since xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcode11

I have recently updated xcode to 11.2.1 (from 10.2.1) and now my UITests are not able to find a value from any switches in the iOS-Settings anymore. Getting the Debugdescription, I found that the UIElement "Switch" does not have any "value" anymore to read out.
To make sure it was an xcode problem, I switched back to xcode 10.2.1 and the value was back.

I was using the xcode simulator with iOS 11.4 and iOS 12.0.
Testing with iOS 13.2.2 showed the value! So it seems to be problem with the older iOS-versions only

xcode 11.2.1 output:

```
Switch, 0x60000081cfc0, {{309.0, 129.0}, {51.0, 31.0}}, label: 'SwitchLabel'
```

xcode 10.2.1 output:

```
Switch, {{343.0, 129.0}, {51.0, 31.0}}, label: 'SwitchLabel', value: 1
```

Until now, I used to check for the value of the switch with:

```
let switchState = app.switches[SwitchLabel].value
```

which turns is now always nil since xcode 11.2.1

Is that a bug in xcode or a new feature I didn't get?

Looks like more people having this problem: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124763